# Bluetooth: hci0: Wrong op received 1 expected 6

Tags: bluetooth

Just reinstalled ubuntu 22.04 and I noticed bluetooth is no longer working. Last time I installed it (first week after release) it was working out of the box

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    4.710959] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.711017] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.711018] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.711030] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.711033] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.711038] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.846890] Bluetooth: hci0: Wrong op received 1 expected 6
[    4.846985] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt func ctrl (-5)
```

Any idea what should I try / do?
The device is a laptop, Lenovo Legion 5 pro

Comment: I see you asked this question 5 months ago. Have you found a solution? I have the same issue on Asus laptop. It happened overnight. One day bluetooth was working perfectly fine, the next day it stopped. I made no updates during that period.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an actual way to solve the problem but here's how Bluetooth started working for me. I have VirtualBox installed with Windows, I thought I would check if Bluetooth works on that VM. I started enabling USB devices in VirtualBox with running Windows on it (wasn't sure which one I should enable, they had ambiguous names). When enabling one of those devices, my computer froze completely (not only Windows but Ubuntu itself). So I had to turn off the laptop the hard way by pressing shut down button for a few seconds. Then after booting it up, Bluetooth started working again.